# hover over one div and change background of a different div

Tags: javascript, image, html, hover

I have been using

```
$(function(){
$("#print").hover(function(){
$("#headerright").toggleClass("img/divright.jpg");
});
});
```

when I mouseover on my div id "print" (which has an image in it) is it possible to change the background of my other div (headderright)?

Comment: you need to use a class name, `img/divright.jpg` is not a class name

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#headerright").toggleClass("img/divright.jpg")
```

you have to give tha class name but you are giving image path. you can do this way

```
.class1{
background-image:url('image1.gif');
}
.class2{
background-image:url('image2.gif');
}
```

and on hove change toggleClass to

```
$("#headerright").toggleClass('class1').toggleClass('class2')
```

and initially put `class1` as a class of your div with id `headerright`

**EDIT**
what i understand from your discussion. change your hover function to this

```
$("#print").hover(function() {
    $("#headerright").css("background-image","url('img/divright.jpg')");
},function(){
   $("#headerright").css("background-image"," ");
});
```

you can try this

Comment: does it matter that I am using div id

Comment: and my image is in my html for my print div id and I need the image off in my header till the print image is hovered over

Comment: i doesn't matter you use id or class name for selecting element

Comment: you mean when you remove mouse from div then image should be removed? and you also don't want that image in css? right?

Comment: ha! sorry this is hard to explain. 
so I have an image in a div id called print, I would like if when I hovered over that image then a background image would appear in a completely different div called headerright

Comment: then i think @Arun P Johny is on right track. that is what you want to do

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$("#print").hover(function() {
    $("#headerright").addClass("my-background");
},function(){
    $("#headerright").removeClass("my-background");
});
```

Then define a css style

```
.my-background{
    background: img/divright.jpg;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/PurgD/)

Comment: I'm sorry. I am so new to webdesign, this is my first site. So would I do my id name where you put class-name? and do I do addid instead? or do I need to change from IDs to class?

Answer (score 0):

```
 Try this: it will change the background:     

 $(function(){
 $("#print").hover(function(){
  $("#headerright").css("background-image","url('img/divright.jpg')");
 });
 });

If u have image on print div it will change the src and display the other image..
```

Comment: thanks so much. It isn't working, but stuff moved so I am sure I am missing something

Answer (score 0):

Create a new class

```
 .backgroungEG {

     background-image :  "img/divright.jpg"
  }


  $("#print").hover(function(){
    $("#headerright").addClass("backgroungEG ");
  });
```

I hope this works..

Comment: does the class and background image to change to need to be in my html as well?

Comment: you can keep that class in your html or in your css. In case if you put in your css, you can use that from multiple html pages.